# Jquery - Changing controls to label (View only form)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, plugins, asp.net-mvc-4

Our client requires a view only form (making controls as readonly is not an acceptable solution :-( ) which displays the value of the text box / drop down / List box (comma delimited values) as label when the user has readonly access to that form. Is there a Jquery plugin which would do this? I don't want to create a separate set of partial views to accomplish this.

Any help in this regard is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Raja

Comment: why don't you just prevent them from posting it?

Comment: I have totally taken out the buttons involving any kinda action but it is not acceptable to the client. They want the user to see only labels if they have readonly access.

Comment: only the labels? So not the inputs with the values? Just the labels like "Title" no useful data "Email" no useful data, etc

Comment: @Raja - you could try to set a cookie via mvc, then read it via jquery and then use jquery [replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) to swap the fields for labels.

Comment: My suggestion would be to have different views with DisplayFor properties to keep things clear. Because if there are any modifications like adding authorization for the form, it would mess up your code further.

Comment: @Sundeep I was going towards that route. But it is just too much work thats why I thought I could go towards an option which can be done at client side.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. I don't advise it.

Declare your helpers with a css class so you can grab them all with a JQuery selector

```
@Html.TextBox("txtName", "20", new { @class = "cssChange" })
```

Use JQuery to change their form to Labels

```
$( ".cssChange" ).replaceWith( function() {
    return "<input type=\"label\" value=\"" + $( this ).html() + "\" />";
});
```

My code was not *tested*. It is purely instructive.

And I recommend against it. I would instead recommend another div with labels and a toggle. But this option is available. good luck.

Comment: This seems to be a nice option. I will take this as a start and head with it. Thanks a bunch Dave :).

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static MvcHtmlString EditorOrDisplayFor<TModel, TProperty>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
        bool canEdit, int boxWidth = 100)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        if (canEdit)
        {
            var editor = htmlHelper.TextBoxFor(expression, new { style = "width: " + boxWidth + "px;" });
            sb.AppendFormat("<div class=\"TextEditor\">{0}</div>", editor);
        }
        else
        {
            var lbl = htmlHelper.LabelFor(expression);
            var hid = htmlHelper.HiddenFor(expression);
            sb.AppendFormat("<div class=\"CanNotEdit\">{0}{1}</div>", lbl, hid);
        }
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(sb.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: then just @Html.EditorOrDisplayFor(m => m.myData, Model.CanEdit.myData, 200)

Comment: The box width was something I ended up needing later.